# Kotlin Multiplatform with iOS: "Use of undeclared type 'KotlinCoroutineContext'"

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm attempting to consume Kotlin multiplatform code (that uses Ktor and Kotlin Coroutines) on iOS.  The framework is generated correctly and can invoke some of the classes/methods exposed without any problem.  However if I try to add following (as is done in https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlinconf-app/blob/master/konfios/konfswift/ui/UI.swift for example).  I get "Use of undeclared type 'KotlinCoroutineContext" (and I see in `SharedCode.h` that it's not present)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SharedCode


public class CoroutineDispatcher: Kotlinx_coroutines_core_nativeCoroutineScope {
    override public func dispatch(context: KotlinCoroutineContext, block: Kotlinx_coroutines_core_nativeRunnable) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}
```

The gradle file for share code includes following (am using Kotlin 1.3.11, Ktor 1.0.1 and Coroutines 1.0.1 along with Gradle 4.7)

```
    commonMain.dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:${Versions.kotlin}"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-common:${Versions.kotlinCoroutines}"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:${Versions.kotlinxSerialization}"

        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core:${Versions.ktor}"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json:${Versions.ktor}"

    }

    androidMain.dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:${Versions.kotlin}"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:${Versions.kotlinCoroutines}"

        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-jvm:${Versions.ktor}"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-jvm:${Versions.ktor}"
    }

    iOSMain.dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:${Versions.kotlinCoroutines}"
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:${Versions.kotlinxSerialization}"

        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:${Versions.ktor}"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-core-ios:${Versions.ktor}"
        implementation "io.ktor:ktor-client-json-ios:${Versions.ktor}"
    }
```

I'm suspecting that issue might be that those symbols aren't explicitly exposed (also tried using `api` instead of `implementation` for coroutine dependencies but that didn't help).

This is what I have so far: https://github.com/joreilly/galway-bus-android/tree/kotlin_native

**UPDATE**:

Tried newly released Kotlin v1.3.20 but now getting following

```
> Task :SharedCode:linkMainDebugFrameworkIOS
warning: skipping /Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-client-ios_debug_ios_x64/1.0.1/7ac4ac71743dbff041cc51a117e1732a9133d3b8/ktor-client-ios.klib. The abi versions don't match. Expected '[5]', found '2'
warning: the compiler versions don't match either. Expected '[1.1.1]', found '1.0.2-release-4769'
error: compilation failed: Could not find "/Users/jooreill/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.ktor/ktor-client-ios_debug_ios_x64/1.0.1/7ac4ac71743dbff041cc51a117e1732a9133d3b8/ktor-client-ios.klib" in [/Users/jooreill/devroot/github/galway-bus-android/SharedCode, /Users/jooreill/.konan/klib, /Users/jooreill/.konan/kotlin-native-macos-1.1.1/klib/common, /Users/jooreill/.konan/kotlin-native-macos-1.1.1/klib/platform/ios_x64].
``
```

Comment: I tried to use Kotlin 1.3.20 EAP which seemingly provides ability to expose symbols etc from multi platform gradle file but ran in to following https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/issues/848

Comment: Sample that uses that new `export` capability - https://github.com/ilmat192/kotlin-native-gradle-samples/blob/master/export-kotlin-multiplatform/framework/build.gradle.kts

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue in your update

`The abi versions don't match. Expected '[5]', found '2'1`

Basically, with Kotlin `1.3.20`, Ktor needs to be upgraded to `1.1.2` and then Gradle `4.10` is required to use the latest Kotlin native. That is because of Gradle Metadata

Before that update, I start to have a new issue to build the iOS artifact regarding the Kotlin Serializer:

`error: compilation failed: Can’t locate polymorphic serializer definition`

To fix that issue I removed the `@Serializable` annotation from classes and provided the `KSerializer` interface separated.

Comment: I had the same issue, I was trying to use ktor `1.1.2` with kotlin `1.3.31` which are incompatible. I had to upgrade ktor to `1.1.5`.

Comment: How do you guys know which version is compatible? Im having the same issue :(

Comment: @ArchieG.Quiñones at this moment, it's better to use the KotlinConf app or the official Kotlin tutorial as a source of truth, also you can check in the issue tracker in the Kotlin's GitHub for reported issues with the latest version.